# Grails g:each tag

Tags: grails

In grails I am trying to get every instance of a domain called Child to be printed out for that authorized user.

I am using the following:

```
 <g:each var="child" in="${Child}">
    <p>Name: ${child.firstname}</p>
    <p>Surname: ${child.lastname}</p>
 </g:each>
```

Each user can have several children (Child) and I want it to list the children for the currently logged in user.
I am using spring source security core plugin for my login etc.

This is my exception:

> Class : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException Message : No such
>   property: firstname for class: com.fyp.timeline.Child Possible
>   solutions: firstname, lastname

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<g:each var="child" in="${user.children}">
   <p>Name: ${child.firstname}</p>
   <p>Surname: ${child.lastname}</p>
</g:each>
```

*user* is an instance of logged in user where

```
User{
    static hasMany=[children:Child]
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm after thanks.
I do now however get a null pointer this is obviously because there are no children entered as yet. Is there a way around this or not? So it will print nothing if there are no children.

Comment: Each is null-safe in groovy, so it shouldn't throw NPE.

Comment: i get a null pointer in the browser and Cannot reference nonstatic symbol 'children' from static context from the IDE.

I dont think this should happen any Ideas??

Comment: Wait, why static? *user* is an instance of loggedin user.

Comment: I assumed  static hasMany=[children:Child] makes it static.

Comment: I have just noticed user dos not seem to be returning anything.
The domain for each user is User. Should user (lowercase) return the currently logged in user instance?

Comment: I assumed static hasMany=[children:Child] makes it static. -> no. To get current logged in user see spring security reference.